# Divising references into two parts

Tags: bibliographies

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alphalph,cite}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,pagebackref=true]{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, citecolor=red , linkcolor= blue}

\begin{document}
We refer to \cite{a2}
\newpage
We refer to \cite{FK1}
\newpage
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{a1} Ref1

\bibitem{a2} Ref2

\bibitem{a3} Ref3

\end{thebibliography}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\makeatletter
\def\@bibitem#1{\item\if@filesw \immediate\write\@auxout
  {\string\bibcite{#1}{\alphalph{\value{\@listctr}}}}\fi\ignorespaces}
\def\@biblabel#1{[\alphalph{#1}]}
\makeatother

\bibitem{FK1} Ref FK1.

\bibitem{FK2} Ref FK2.

\bibitem{FK3} Ref FK2.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

> In my thesis I would like to create two groups of references. The first one is for main references and will be as usual 1], [2], [3],....The second one will be for my own papers and will be [FK1], [FK2], [FK3]......I hope that it works when I use `hyperref`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `\bibitem` command, like regular `\item`, has an optional argument to set the label manually. This is compatible with `hyperref` and backreferences.

How to change the title of the bibliography depends on the documentclass (and whether biblatex is used or not). For `article` the title is called `\refname`, which you can modify with `\renewcommand`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alphalph,cite}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,pagebackref=true]{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, citecolor=red , linkcolor= blue}

\begin{document}
We refer to \cite{a2}
\newpage
We refer to \cite{FK1}
\newpage
\renewcommand\refname{Main references}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{a1} Ref1

\bibitem{a2} Ref2

\bibitem{a3} Ref3

\end{thebibliography}
\renewcommand\refname{Own papers}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem[FK1]{FK1} Ref FK1.

\bibitem[FK2]{FK2} Ref FK2.

\bibitem[FK3]{FK3} Ref FK2.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]